# Tweepy not defined

Tags: tweepy

I am receiving this message:

> auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
>
> NameError: name 'tweepy' is not defined

after trying this:

```
from credentials import *

import tweepy
from time import sleep

from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q='#Kanye').items(10):
        try:
                print('Tweet by @' + tweet.user.screen_name)

        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
                print(e.reason)

        except StopIteration:
                break
```

Comment: Your code does not match the error message.  `auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(...)` vs. `auth = OAuthHandler(...)`.  Which is correct?

Comment: They're both copied directly from terminal, I'm very new and not sure sorry,

Answer (score -1):

Be sure you've not named your script tweepy.py